# Find the complex roots of $4x^2+16$ using QR method

Tags: matrices, polynomials, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, octave

$$p(x)=4x^2+16$$
$$m(x)=\frac{p(x)}{4}=x^2+4$$

Now, I can determine the Companion matrix of $x^2+4$:

$$A=A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ -4 \\ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

QR decomposition (using Octave):

[Q,R]=qr(A)

$$Q_1\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ -1 \\ -1  \ \  \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
$$R_1=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \ \ \  0 \\ 0  \ \  \ \ 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A_2=R_1 Q_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ 1 \\ -4     \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
$$R_2=\begin{pmatrix} -4 \ \ \  0 \\ 0  \ \  \ \ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Q_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ \ \  1 \\ 1 \ \  \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A_3=R_2 Q_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ -4 \\ 1     \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
$$R_3=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \ \ \  0 \\ 0  \ \  \ \ 4 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$Q_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \ \ \  -1 \\ -1  \ \  \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

How can I find the complex roots $2i$,$-2i$ (in general, complex roots of polynomials) using this method?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that a matrix algorithm is intended and not the transformation to the normalized equation $0=x^2+qx+r$ with its solution formula?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for an algorithm to find all complex roots of a polynomial. Recently, I have read an article about Companion matrix and I'm thinking about using a numerical method to find complex eigenvalues. @LutzL

Comment: I would recommend the Bairstow algorithm. Another algorithm that finds complex roots in complex conjugate pairs is the Jenkins-Traub algorithm in its RPOLY variant, which can be found at netlib.org. You can also apply the Newton algorithm over complex numbers. And another algorithm that finds complex roots also from real initial values is the Laguerre method. Study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials and come back for further questions.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the real QR algorithm, you only get a upper triangular matrix as limit if all eigenvalues are real. With complex eigenvalues, you get $2×2$ matrix blocks on the diagonal for any complex conjugate pair.

In the complex case, you get a unitarian matrix for $Q$ by employing complex shifts. A first strategy is to compute the shift as eigenvalue of the bottom-most $2×2$ diagonal block. Which again makes the matrix formulation for degree $2$ one big circular computation.